# iOS plot 3d graph library

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, plot

I'm searching a library which help me to plot 3D graphs. I would like something similar to [this page](http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/) or [GNUPlot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). I would make all the calculations, I only want a library that can print my (x, y, z) values to the iPhone/iPad screen.

Searching on google, I found [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/), but as far as I know it can only print 2D graphs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ManiacDev recently posted a good overview of good frameworks for plotting 3D charts on iOS:

http://maniacdev.com/2012/08/open-source-ios-library-for-easily-creating-3d-charts/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm searching something to plot "maths" data, more like 3D shapes from xyz coordinates. However, your answer can be good for another project I have on mind :)

Comment: Then it's worth looking at using OpenGL. [Rend](https://github.com/antonholmquist/rend-ios) might be a good choice.