# Path line plotting graphics library/engine for C/C++?

Tags: android, ios, graph, plot, line

I am looking for a C or C++ library/engine that will draw a path line plot (2D and/or 3D), given a set of segment inputs. Each segment is generally connected to the previous segment, and each segment includes distance, a degree bearing, and a declination. See the images below for sample output. 2D would require only distance and bearing, while 3D would require distance, bearing, and declination.

I'm not looking for a charting/reporting library.

Does anyone know of any libraries, preferably open source, that would suffice to draw a path line plot given inputs?

[image]

Ultimately I'd like to draw something like this (a map):

[image]

Comment: What is the target platform/device/OS?

Comment: iOS and eventually Android. Though, I'd assume it's possible for a library to operate with both, seamlessly. If it's targeted to just iOS, that is acceptable.

Comment: Is it for a flat world, spherical or ellipsoidal Earth?

Comment: Flat is the priority. It would be nice if the same library or another library can draw a 3D representation as well (with segment distances, declinations, and directions/azimuths). For 3D, I'm not sure spherical or ellipsoidal matters; I want to represent  an area like shown in the cube here: http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/doc_en/doc_en_75.html#Cont3-sample. But again: flat is the priority.

Comment: Since you ruled out charting libraries, I won't cite DISLIN now (http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/). Done GIS-type plotting; all it takes is a GIS front-end for your platform + a bit of trigonometry in a cycle (of course things get hairy for ellipsoidal Earth, a.k.a forward and inverse geodetic problems). You may be better off asking for lightweight GIS solutions at GIS SE.

Comment: Re-reading your comment: you may need a plotting library, a quick SE search yielded some candidates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264347/ios-plot-3d-graph-library and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724887/ios-chart-libraries

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you to look at another approach utilizing SVG graphics. The simplest way is to use iOS's and Android's built-in web views to host SVGs, though it's not a pure C++, of course. Also you can use native SVG libraries for these platforms. I'm not familiar with iOS, but I used code.google.com/p/svg-android/ for a map-related app, and it works very well with big maps. Also you can use a cross-platform C++ library such as http://code.google.com/p/simple-svg/, but this one may require a lot of work to support rendering in iOS, I suppose. So look for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break down what the library would need to do,
you end up with some pretty basic functions,
which you probably won't find encapsulated as a library
since they are pretty trivial.

Step 1: "Segments to 3d Points"

a) Create a unit vector along your reference axis.
b) Scale it by the segment distance.
c) Rotate it by the bearing.
d) Rotate it by the declination.
(Note: Assuming bearing and declination are orthogonal you shouldn't run into any trouble.)
e) Add the start of the segment (aka the last vector).

Step 2: "3d Points to 2d Points"

a) Multiply your 3d vector through a perspective or orthognal projection matrix.

Step 3: "2d points to lines"

a) Use the bresenham line algorithm to gte the individual pixels.

Once you finished Step 2 and actually have lines in 2-point representation
all drawing libraries should do.
No magic at all ;)

(Note: There are lots of flight tracking/mapping apps out there that do a mighty fine job.)

Comment: This is probably what I'll end up doing. Then I'll package this in my own library allowing you to simply pass in a list of points.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing for a long time.

You can use [Skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/) from Android which is cross platform and can run on iOS, but it is kind of a big library for such a simple problem.

You should take a look at [Ejecta](http://impactjs.com/ejecta) from phoboslab.org.
It is a javascript canvas implementation for iOS based on openGL/ES.
You can remove the javascript part and use the canvas directly.
Plus it is open source and works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

[Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) is what you're looking for. OGL programming presented in a GLView with access to primitive methods that you need to draw what you want. You need some knowledge of C++ and android-ndk, follow the tutorials in the web and follow [my tips on debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314789/crash-in-android-native-while-changing-to-new-activity/10332018#10332018).